# How to insert more than one line of data in a single cell of UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Can I know how can we insert more than one line of data into a single cell of a UITableView,
Just Like, I want the output in a single cell to be like :

KPK

Developer

Infosystems

INDIA

Answer (score 1):

```
            UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 80)];
            myLabel.text = @"KPK";
            myLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
            myLabel.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
           [cell addSubview:myLabel];

           UILabel *myLabel1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 201, 200, 80)];
            myLabel1.text = @"Developer";
            myLabel1.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
            myLabel1.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
            [cell addSubview:myLabel1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **\n** as you are using in your string.

Set **numberOfLines** to 4 to allow for any number of lines.

```
label.numberOfLines = 4;
```

Update the label frame to match the size of the text using **sizeWithFont:**. If you don't do this your text will be vertically centered or cut off.

```
UILabel *label; // set frame to largest size you want
...
CGSize labelSize = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font
                      constrainedToSize:label.frame.size
                          lineBreakMode:label.lineBreakMode];
label.frame = CGRectMake(
label.origin.x, label.orgin.y, 
label.size.width, labelSize.height);
label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"KPK\nDeveloper\nInfosystems\nIndia"];
```

Now you just need to add the label in your cell.

```
[cell addSubView:label];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can place \n in text.Not sure if that works else you can make custom cell for multiple line records.

Answer (score 0):

set tablerow height and Use label in your tableview

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom cell, add 4 labels in it, to display all of your required info. Checkout the following tutorial to see how you can make custom cell.

http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/30/iphone-sdk-tutorial-part-6-creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder-uitableview/

Answer (score 0):

Use a uilabel and add that one as the subview if your tableview cell.you can specify the number of lines of uilabel

```
   label.numberOfLines = 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way is creating a custom `UITableViewCell` implementation, or programmatically adding `UILabel`s to the cell's contentView.

I.e.:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 200, 30)];
label.text = @"MyText";
label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[cell.contentView addSubview:label];
[label release]; // Never forget this!
```

When adding the additional rows you should update the first line definition to correctly offset the new rows. Eg. the second label should have something like this:

```
UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 35, 200, 30)];
```

When you are done, you should implement the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method in the table's delegate, because you have to define the correct height for the new cell. In your example, for 4 labels you should implement something like this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath)indexPath {
    if (is_one_of_my_modified_cells) {
        return 35*4 + 5;
    }

    return 44; // default height
}
```

Try it and let me know.